# Any possible problem to drive train for tires of different circumference?

Tags: tires

How much difference in mm tread depth between front tires on a fwd suv before it may cause problems?

Comment: Fwd transaxle is designed to allow drive with front wheels at different speeds when turning, so a few mm would not hurt, it becomes a very very slight turn. It is the awd vehicles where a transfer case expects the same drive on back and front that causes damage

Comment: @Chris - I'd bet the OP means "**4**WD" (four wheel drive) in place of fwd (front wheel drive) considering they are stating an SUV, but I wouldn't know for sure.

Comment: Possibly, i know my cx-9 comes in an actual fwd skew or awd skew. As the OP mentions front tires, I recon it may be actual fwd

Answer (score 1):

Each car maker has their own specs on how much circumference difference is allowed. See [this post](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/replace-4-tires-on-awd/) on why they have to be close